# Close aperture on Canon 1100D

Tags: video, dslr, canon

I have a Canon 1100D and a 50mm f/1.8 lens. Seems like the camera insists on shooting at default aperture, but I won't have it, since that results in a mostly blurred video. How can I adjust the aperture?

Comment: Yes you can, I would consider looking in the manual for your Canon 1100D

Comment: It looks like the manual is [available here](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300004730/02/eosrt3-eos1100d-im2-c-en.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it turns out that the shutter change is *automatic* depending on the amount of light available. You cannot alter the shutter manually. What this means in practical terms is that, with room lightning you are 99% guaranteed that you're shooting wide open, which just blurs everything and makes the video mode pretty much unusable. Thanks Canon.

Comment: In M mode, you can change the aperture.

Answer (score 0):

Blurriness is also affected by focus.

Apart from the aperture make sure that you have focused on your subject. (Again read the manual on how to do this)